Proper downloading of files from S3 using pre-signed URLs
I am trying to refactor my current existing code base to download multiple files from S3. If I understand correctly the documentation, I am doing too many requests in a short period of time (1), (2) & (3).
Looking at the AWS SDK documentation it appears that a proper implementation exists, as described at:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/feature-retry-behavior.html

However I have been unable to use it so far. I did check the example page:
See "Upload or download large files" at:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/csharp_s3_code_examples.html

It looks like AmazonS3Client does not accept pre-signed URL as input (output only). Same story for TransferUtility
Anyone knows how to use AWS SDK (or c# alternative) to properly download multiple files from S3 using pre-signed URLs ? I have a reproducable case where a basic HTTP client setup fails for number of files equals 7000.
References:

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/http-5xx-errors-s3
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/feature-retry-behavior.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/retries-timeouts.html


You don't use the AWS SDK to fetch an object via a pre-signed URL. Use a standard HTTP library. Implement your own backoff/retry as needed or find a library to help.

@jarmod, care to post a suggestion implementation as an answer ? The following piece of code fails for me.

IMO you should be in control of the requests rather than relying on auto-backoff strategies, because in this situation you KNOW that it will hit the limits.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/performance-tuning-s3-throttling.html#:~:text=Amazon%20S3%20has%20a%20limit,be%20throttled%20by%20Amazon%20S3.
AWS throttles you at 5500 GETs per second which is less than your 7000 splat.
Because you already have presigned urls, you don't need to use any AWS SDK for actually making the fetches. It sounds like you are fetching from 1 single client, so you should just fetch a subset of objects in batches e.g. fetch 1000 at a time.
If this is spread over 7000 separate clients accessing the same S3 object, then you should be implementing CloudFront + caching and using presigned CloudFront URLS (not s3 urls) and let CF farm out the requests.

Yes, while working with a larger number of files such as 7000 using pre-signed URLs with AWS SDK is not the most suitable approach.
You can use HttpClient with Exponential Backoff. But before that, you will be required to list all the pre-signed URLs for each file you want to download.
HttpClient will help you to send individual download requests with each pre-signed URL and the Exponential backoff retry mechanism will help retry failed downloads.
public async Task DownloadFilesWithBackoff(List<string> preSignedUrls)
{
    int retryCount = 0;
    TimeSpan delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

    foreach (string url in preSignedUrls)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    break; // Success, exit loop
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException ex)
                {
                    retryCount++;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Download failed (attempt {retryCount}): {ex.Message}");
                    if (retryCount >= 3) // Adjust retry limit as needed
                    {
                        throw; // Re-throw exception after exceeding retries
                    }
                    await Task.Delay(delay);
                    delay *= 2; // Increase delay for next attempt
                }
            }
            // Process downloaded content from the response
        }
    }
}

You can also consider implementing Multithreading with this which can help you download files concurrently.

I didn't downvote but I'm guessing the reason someone else did is this backoff strategy. The .Net Foundation has a project called Polly and its an Fault and Tolerance Framework with Retry's and JittedBacksOffs which is better than your implementation. eg https://stackoverflow.com/q/62913614/495455 but with the JittedBackOff algorithm.

you can clone your s3 bucket on your local directory which will automatically download your videos

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
